# Are they any accessibility concerns with having a large button with a timer embedded in it?

Tags: accessibility

I am researching a requirement for a project and I have worries that a button with a timer embedded in it may not be accessible. My concern is that having the timer and button together on the page would create a confusing experience for users with screen readers. Note that this time limit will not be extendable because it represents the time someone has to "purchase" a ticket before other processes mark their ticket as abandoned.

Does anyone here have resources or advice about this specific situation? I haven't found anything for or against this yet.

At this time, my current thought is to have the timer announce itself at reasonable intervals and then ensure it can't be focused on by the keyboard so it doesn't disrupt navigating to the button.

[image: This is the button in question]

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question!

The short answer is that **this should be fine**, because the timer is not an operable element (you can't "click" it).

I am pretty sure that the timer semantic will be stripped if you put it inside the button (i.e. in the button's DOM subtree), so any changes to the timer value will essentially be manipulating a text node inside the button label. When you focus the button, the accessible name will therefore be "button RSVP 14 59" or some such.

However, I would think carefully about how you want to present this timer value. I assume it's "time left" or "time remaining". These are (arguably) the most compelling text alternatives for the little stopwatch icon you are using, so you'd most likely get "button RSVP time remaining 14 59".

Consider creating a live region somewhere (offscreen) then you can copy the timer value into the text content of the live region every X seconds. This will cause a timed announcement of the timer value independently of the visual updates. Adjust the delay value to suit. Remember also to copy any other status messages (such as "time's up!") into the same live region.

If you want to **preserve** the timer semantic, you'll probably have to move it outside the button (in the DOM, not necessarily visually). You can then add something like `aria-details` or `aria-describedby` to the `<button>`, pointing at the timer element.

If you take this approach, the accessible name will be "RSVP" and the accessible description will be the timer value. Most Assistive Tech (e.g. screen readers) has a preference setting to suppress or include descriptions as you tab around a UI, which means that some users may not "get" the timer value from focusing the button.

But if the timer is still in the DOM, and not actually hidden from the accessibility tree, it would probably work just fine, even if you use CSS to draw the timer "inside" the button, visually speaking. The timer will still be there for screen readers to browse, most likely "next" in the DOM, it will just be separate from the button that seems to contain it.

Note: the announcement of time values by screen readers is notoriously unpredictable.  Unfortunately the `datetime` attribute which is supposed to address the semantics of time values, does not seem to have any impact on what actually comes out of the speech synth (at time of writing). Apparently, fixing this issue requires alignment with the browser and OS vendors. Screen reader users have made it completely clear: They are familiar with the problem, and they don't want it fixed (badly) by web content authors.

So, even if the time value seems to be announced in a strange way (for example "00:00" is announced as "midnight" even if it is marked-up as a duration value), please constrain any temptation to "hack" the time value phonetically for the sake of speech synth output. Different speech synths pronounce things differently, even using the same screen reader. Always consider that there will be other kinds of assistive tech, such as Braille devices, which wont necessarily make sense of 'cleverly designed' utterances.

Comment: FYI There is a discussion on the ARIA github board about what are being called "secondary actions". These are pretty common UI features, but do not (yet) exist in ARIA. In this case, the timer is not operable, so it does not count as an "action", let alone a secondary one, but I'm going to link to this issue, because I think this kind of "timed button" is far from unusual. The discussion is at https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/1440

Comment: As you pointed out, the timer here is not an action in the sense the issue you're linking to describes them, and the additions to ARIA spec that might resolve this issue (`aria-actions`) aren't relevant here since these do not address the limitation imposed on elements nested inside the button (which would be stripped of any semantics).

It is however an element that is related to the button, so extracting it from the button and using aria-details or aria-describedby like you suggested is a reasonable option.

Comment: Thanks @brennanyoung this is very helpful insight! Creating a live region offscreen seems like a great first approach to this problem. Thank you for the warning about how time values are announced as well. I could see myself easily being drawn into trying to "correct" a case where "00:00" was being announced as midnight. 

Once we're done with the scoping phase and start building out the button, I will report back with which strategy you suggested was an ideal solution for us.